# C# Dictionary Key/Value Ienumerable type not compatiable with Array/List

Tags: c#

I have below piece of code and it throws error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary>' to
>    'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary>'

I expect compiler to understand `IEnumerable` and `List` are compatible but it throws error.  Please explain why is it like this?

```
Dictionary<string, List<DataRow>> sampleData = new Dictionary<string, List<DataRow>>();
                Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<DataRow>> schedules = sampleData;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Lists and Ienums are compatible but not the same, you need to cast or change both to the same

Comment: I don't think dictionaries a co-variant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `Dictionary` is not covariant, so you can't use less-derived types for its generic parameters.

Suppose your code compiled - then you could do this:

```
Dictionary<string, List<DataRow>> sampleData = 
    new Dictionary<string, List<DataRow>>();

Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<DataRow>> schedules = sampleData;

schedules["KeyOne"] = new DataRow[] {null};   
// should fail since an array is not a list, and the object type requires a list.
```

Answer (score 1):

A workaround could be

```
Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<DataRow>> schedules = 
       sampleData.ToEnumerableDic();
```

With a generic extension

```
public static Dictionary<T1, IEnumerable<T2>> ToEnumerableDic<T1,T2>(this Dictionary<T1, List<T2>> sampleData) {
    return sampleData.Select(x => new { a = x.Key, b = x.Value.AsEnumerable() })
        .ToDictionary(x => x.a, x => x.b);
}
```