# Why cannot a dictionary convert to an IEnumerable

Tags: c#, casting

Consider:

```cs
public IReadOnlyDictionary<Object, IEnumerable<Object>> readOnlyDictionary
{
    get { return dictionary;}
}

private Dictionary<Object, List<Object>> dictionary;
```

Produces the error:

> Error CS0266
> Cannot implicitly convert type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<object,System.Collections.Generic.List>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyDictionary<object, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

`List<Object>` implements `IEnumerable`, and returning an `IEnumerable` from a `List` works fine. Why does this fail when placed within a container such as a `Dictionary`?

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,d3599058f8d79be0

Comment: @OlivierRogier How does that help?

Comment: If a link to the underlying source concisely answers the question then you should really provide a commentary as to why that's the case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Dictionary Key/Value Ienumerable type not compatiable with Array/List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39393068/c-sharp-dictionary-key-value-ienumerable-type-not-compatiable-with-array-list)

Comment: @GSerg Yes, thank you. That goes into a bit more detail and has given me the keyword `covariant` to look for further information at least. :)

Comment: @HarryWill https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14263964/c-sharp-generic-inheritance-and-covariance-part-2/14264436#14264436

Comment: @GSerg and Olivier: added your links to the answer since they explain it in more detail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>` but a `Dictionary<Object, List<Object>>` is not a `Dictionary<Object, IEnumerable<Object>>`. This simply doesn't work. You either have to change the return type to `IReadOnlyDictionary<Object, List<Object>>` or the type of the dictionary to `Dictionary<Object, IEnumerable<Object>>`.

Shamelessly copy&pasting the good links from GSerg and Olivier:

- [Why it doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39393584/284240)
- [Ok, i got, but wth is *covariant*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14263964/c-sharp-generic-inheritance-and-covariance-part-2/14264436#14264436)